# How to solve collisions between Lager and OTP's Logger in Erlang?

Tags: logging, erlang, lager

I have an Erlang project in OTP 22 which uses the built-in **logger** module for logging (which was added in OTP 21).

My project uses the dependency "amqp_client" (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang-client).

This dependency uses **lager** library for logging, so **lager** is also one of the dependencies in my project.

From the moment I've added **lager** to my project, the logs that were done via **logger** are not working anymore (I guess that's because **lager** is overriding some logging-handler of the VM which **logger** also uses, or something like this?)

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

(This should be a comment to the answer provided by evnu, but I don't have the rep required for comment yet)

In [lager](https://github.com/erlang-lager/lager/blob/d88b3663b9e6d5313207b30869deb160ffd503ec/src/lager_app.erl#L186-L197) you can see how it removes the default logger handler.
You have 2 options if you leave `error_logger_redirect` on:

1. Rely on lager for everything (configure lager for the whole project)
2. Add your own logger handler (you can do it in the sys.config, this is what I do for my projects)

Untested sys.config example for 2:

```
[
    {kernel, [
        {logger, [
            {handler, my_default, logger_std_h, #{
                level => debug,
                config => #{
                    sync_mode_qlen => 200,
                    overload_kill_enable => true
                },
                formatter => {logger_formatter, #{template => [time," ",pid," ",level,": ",msg,"\n"]}}
            }}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misread the question, it is about Erlang, not Elixir.

---

See [the troubleshooting section of amqp](https://hexdocs.pm/amqp/readme.html):

> **Lager conflicts with Elixir logger**
>
> Lager is used by rabbit_common and it is not Elixir's best friend yet.
>   You need a workaround.
>
> In mix.exs, you have to load `:lager` before `:logger`.
>
> ```
> extra_applications: [:lager, :logger, :amqp]
> ```
>
> Here is a sample configuration to silent rabbit_common logging.
>
> ```
> config :lager,
>  error_logger_redirect: false,
>  handlers: [level: :critical]
> ```
>
> Check out Lager and RabbitMQ documentation for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I asked about Erlang (not Elixir). Is there any solution for Erlang? Note that in Erlang I do not load logger anywhere (so I can't "load it before lager")